# Multiple Installs of Chrome

Tags: macos, applications, google-chrome

For the past 6 years of my career I have been using Firefox/Firebug for web development. In the beginning it was the most powerful client side toolset. But now I am finding most of my colleagues. Especially the younger ones only use Chrome. They don't even have Firefox installed. This makes it harder to collaborate.

I've loved using Chrome for personal browsing and Firefox for development. But I am ready to switch over to using Chrome for development as well. Is it possible to have two installs of Chrome on OSX? Maybe even one install of Chromium or some other development build and the release version of Chrome?

Comment: In the end I decided to use Chrome Canary for development and Chrome for web browsing. Not sure how stable Canary is, but so far it's working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

- Simply use Chrome's profile feature in Settings to configure multiple profiles.
- For different versions of Chrome, download them and rename them, then turn off automatic updating.
- Chromium does not interfere with Chrome, in the same way that Chrome Canary does not interfere with Chrome either.

Comment: I wasn't able to get two different versions of Chrome working. But everything else worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can run *Chrome* in separate profile directories, e.g.

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --user-data-dir="$PWD/Foo"
```

so they won't interfere with the existing installation.

Add `-n` for `open to open a new instance even if one is already running.